# Size taken by Dalvik Virtual Machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik, android-framework

I am trying to understand how much memory is allocated for each process in Android. As I understand, for each app process there is a seperate instance of Zygote process and Zygote will fork Dalvik VM.

I wrote a small sample java application which just print's "hello world" in a loop. Later invoked Dalvik VM through ADB shell. Now, Procrank command shows that,

PID      Vss      Rss      Pss      Uss  cmdline
 9374    7556K    7556K    3600K    3384K  dalvikvm

USS which is shown here is 3384k.

Later, I wrote a small android program with one activity and TextView. Now procrank shows

PID      Vss      Rss      Pss      Uss  cmdline
 6540   37256K   35124K    4387K    3392K  com.example.helloworld

My questions are:

1. If each app process contains Dalvik VM, won't it take more memory?
2. How do we know, the size of memory occupied by VM and the size occupied by the Java process?

My understanding might be wrong with respect to Dalvik and how it is invoked and the memory occupied by VM in each process.

Any insights are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I waited for quite some time expecting an expert answer for this question . Let me share you what i know .

Answer to first question : "If each app process contains Dalvik VM, won't it take more memory?"

The Dalvik heap is preloaded with classes and data by zygote (loading over 1900 classes as of Android version 2.2). When zygote forks to start an android application, the new application gets a copy-on-write mapping of this heap. As Dan Borstein says below, this helps with memory reduction as well as application startup time.

`It's used in Android to amortize the RAM footprint of the large amount of effectively-read-only data (technically` `writable but rarely actually written) associated with common library classes across all active VM processes. 1000+` `classes get preloaded by the system at boot time, and each class consumes at least a little heap for itself, including` `often pointing off to a constellation of other objects. The heap created by the preloading process gets` `shared copy-on-write with each spawned VM process (but again doesn't in practice get written much). This saves` `hundreds of kB of dirty unpageable RAM per process and also helps speed up process startup.`

To your 2 question: "How do we know, the size of memory occupied by VM and the size occupied by the Java process?"

I didnt understand what you mean by 'size occupied by the Java process'  [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813) link for clarity about memory in dalvik.

In addition to procrank we can also use `adb shell dumpsys meminfo 'your apps package name'`   check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool)  for more info on dumpsys.