# Android findstr not found while accessing adb

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to execute adb shell command from java by the help of Process

```
   String command = "adb shell dumpsys battery | findstr status";
   Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

It return **/system/bin/sh: findstr: not found**

If I run the same command from **command prompt** and **python script** it display the expected result.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11201711/3531756) helps.

Comment: @Tushar yes i already read that and i got the output running via command prompt or terminal

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run adb on the mobile and the findstr command is AFIK only on windows. The linux equivalent grep is not allowed on the androids build in shell so you can just execute `dumpsys battery` and filter the relevent parts with your own code.

Comment: by using grep instead of findstr is working and thanks for your contribution