# How to find out Android device diagonal display width or screen size using adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I need to find out device-width to keep track the set the different actions based on different width of every device, which is further used to write a script to automate the process. Through my research I get to find out using certain commands like-

```
$ adb shell wm size
Output-Physical size: 720x1280

adb shell wm density
Output-Physical density: 320
```

Curious to know, if there is any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

precise format of the dumpsys command depends on the hardware vendor (of graphics chipset/driver and handset itself) but you should be able to find that info in the adb shell dumpsys display output

Comment: I have tried that as well, device diagonal screen size is not there

Comment: Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/whats-the-android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool-and-what-are-its-benefits

Comment: dumpsys window displays
will return something like this-Display: mDisplayId=0
  init=1080x1920 480dpi cur=1080x1920 app=1080x1920 rng=1080x1005-1920x1845
  layoutNeeded=false. This is not the thing I need.