# Which is the real memory usage of Android app?

Tags: android, memory

When a run a simple application consisting of a single activity with a layout containing a button, the memory usage reported in the Android Studio Monitor is around 3MB. But when I take a look at the app memory usage in the task manager it reports 25MB.

So my question is which is the correct memory usage and why is there a discrepancy between these two?

--Edit - Task Manager that was included with the Samsung Tablet

Comment: what is task manager ? from where did you get this task manager? is it from android studio?

Comment: android studio showing your project's memory while Task manager is showing memory occupied by android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can check it yourself by using `dumpsys` utility which is part of ADB. Details about this utility can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11201711/2463035).

I think that you'll find out that Android Studio reflects the memory usage more accurately.